# Alerts in Metabase - Input variable based reports

Tags: report, alerts, metabase

We have created alerts (for reports without input variables, like stock report) in metabase and are working fine.

We have created sales reports for client which is based on date range.
Now client ask for alerts on sales reports on daily basis, that means, default value for From & To date should be Today's date.

We have set alerts but not getting in our mailbox.

Can you please let me know how can i achieve this?

- Today's date as default value in input variable
- Get report in my inbox every morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed variables and used cast(now() as date) to get data for current date and alert was set at EOD, so it is working as expected.

After doing this when i set alerts, i got report in my inbox at scheduled time.